# What steps to minimize corrosion in mountain bike in non-climate controlled storage

Tags: mountain-bike, storage

I will be putting my mountain bike into a non-climate controlled storage space.

I will be there about 90 days.

Is there anything I can do to minimize rust and corrosion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as there is not much moisture present, 90 days should have no effect on your bike. I've never kept my bikes in climate-controlled storage and never had any problems. But if you are concerned, I suggest washing the bike before storing it (muck and grime can accelerate corrosion), drying it thoroughly, and lubing the chain with quality lube. If you expect huge variations in moisture level, you can also use spray-based rust preventers on the cassette, but apart from that there's not much else.

Comment: I cleaned my chain and gears using a diluted Simple Green solution.

I used what I normally use which is WD-40 Dirt & Dust Resistant Dry Lube PTFE spray.

I have found that wet chain lubricants attract a lot of dust and dirt particles.

Andy

Comment: This is a case for using WD40 on a bike - spray the chain, cassette and anything that looks like it might rust (except brakes :) )  with WD40. Inflate tires to max pressure if you are not hanging the bike.  When being out of storage, clean and lube with chain your preferred lube. I would not trust dry lube to prevent rust.